# Split large log file (~ 72,493 KB) content in Delphi TreeView

Tags: delphi, treeview, delphi-7, logfile

I have a large sized log file approx. 72,493 KB.

While opening it even in `notepad` its taking 5-6 seconds, and more than 20 minutes in my `delphi7` application.

I want to split the file in `Delphi-7` `treeview` and want it to load step wise, e.g. on click on `..more..` more details from that log file should be displayed in `delphi treeview`.

Please let me know the possible ways for this.

Thank you.

Comment: You don't want to do that. The tree view control won't handle that much data. Virtual tree view is better. How to parse the file into a tree structure only you can know.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : Yes it is `virtualtree` as it reads all the log files available in LOG folder and reads its content. But, the point here is if some file is having too much content it is really tough to maintain that load and as I said it takes almost 15-20 minutes to load all the files. Is there any way out there so that I can split this file's content?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible but you've not given any detail. If you want to read less, do just that.

Comment: @David, I was about to say the same, but how would you determine the row count to setup the root node count without reading the file (considering there's no structure, just pure lines ended by the line feeds) ?

Comment: @TLama I guess you have to set it to the number that you read. When you get to the bottom, read more, increase row count.

Comment: @David, then you'll lose scrollbars (but the OP is fine with it, I missed that requirement).

Comment: Scanning the file and generating a time-tree should not be very slow, you build the time-tree in your Treeview and when user click on one time, you load the log for that time period. You can also use other criteria to build the tree.

Comment: Map the log-file into a memory mapped file and than jump directly to the place in memory where your scrollbar is. That way you only load the text that's currently in view.